# How to convert List<Map<String, Object>> to <List<Map<String, String>>?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

How can I convert a `List<Map<String, Object>>` to a `<List<Map<String, String>>`?

My `Object` values are `Integer`, `String`, and `LocalDate`.

```java
Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (Map<String, Object> element: list) {
    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : element.entrySet()) {
        newMap.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

This doesn't work for me.

***Updated***
Thanks guys in comments for help!

Wanna post here full algorythm, maybe it can be usefull for someone

```
// data preparing
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("key1", 4);
        Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("key2", date);
        List<Map<String, Object>> subject = new ArrayList<>();
        subject.add(0, map1);
        subject.add(1, map2);

        System.out.println(subject);

        Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<Map<String,String>> newList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map<String, Object> element : subject) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : element.entrySet()) {
                newMap.put(entry.getKey(), String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                newList.add(newMap);
            }
        }
        //test results
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println(newList.get(0).get("key1").getClass());
        System.out.println(newList.get(1).get("key2").getClass());
        System.out.println(newList);
```

Comment: You can use `entry.getValue().toString()` or `String.valueOf(entry.getValue())` instead of `(String) entry.getValue()`.

Comment: Well when your objects are not strings, what do you want to do? convert them? skip them?

Comment: @khelwood wanna convert them into strings

Comment: Have you tried `entry.getValue().toString()` instead of `(String) entry.getValue())`?

Comment: It would help to post a complete method, as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . Include error messages, whether runtime or compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace *(String) entry.getValue()* for *String.valueOf*, like that:

```
Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (Map<String, Object> element: list) {
    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : element.entrySet()) {
        newMap.put(entry.getKey(), String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more functional approach to this would be:

```
    private List<Map<String, String>> retypeFunctional(List<Map<String, Object>> list) {
        List<Map<String, String>> result = list.stream()
            .map(map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> String.valueOf(e.getValue()))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        return result;
    }
```

Remember to:

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

among other more obvious imports.

Comment: While this is correct, I’m not sure it’s an improvement over a simple loop.

Comment: The functionalists (am I coining a term?) would say it is, but I might agree with you. On simple character count (functional: 194; for loop, including variable declarations: 293), one could say it's an improvement as well, but who's counting?